# How to make horizontal scroll smoother?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, scroll, elementor

I added this code to my WordPress based website to make its front page horizontal. But it's not smooth and I cannot add scroll snap or anchor points. Can you help me about these? My website is https://kozb.art

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function replaceVerticalScrollByHorizontal( event ) {
  if ( event.deltaY !== 0 ) {
   window.scroll(window.scrollX + event.deltaY * 2, window.scrollY );
   event.preventDefault();
  }
 }

 const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia( '(min-width: 770px)' );

 if ( mediaQuery.matches ) {
  window.addEventListener( 'wheel', replaceVerticalScrollByHorizontal );
 }
</script>
```

Edit: Here's my CSS code to make front page horizontal:

```
.elementor-section-wrap{
    display: inline-flex;
}

.elementor-section{
 width:100vw;
}
body{
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overscroll-behavior-y: none;
}

@media (max-width:768px){
    .elementor-section-wrap{
      display: block;
    }
    body{
      overflow-y: auto;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overscroll-behavior-x: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your website actually looks *pretty good*! But when you say "smooth", do you mean you want the scroll wheel to jump to the new "page" without additional scroll wheel action? If so, you current code has no "state" on what the current page is, nor does it have any conditions to even "auto scroll" to the next page when scroll wheel is handled.

Comment: @mardubbles if you visit https://kozb.art/about, you can see the smooth scroll in vertical pages. I don't mean to jump sections, I mean when you scroll it's not stopping in the right positions, you can see the left and right sections' background colors while scrolling. I want to add snap scroll between sections with smooth scrolling. I mean, when you scroll the page, your scroll event will stop when the next section fully came up to your screen.

Comment: But I don't think snap is applied to kozb.art/about, right? It just looks like a smooth scroll. What you want is a snap scroll that can stop the section smoothly from the horizontal scroll?

Comment: @lowfront Yes, exactly. I don't need scroll snap on vertical pages, because they all have 1 color in background. But in the front page I need to seperate different backgrounds. Without scroll snap or smooth scroll, front page is not looking good I think. When you scroll to the 2nd section (with the yellow background), you are still seeing the black and white backgrounds from other sections on the screen and that's annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need animation knowledge to move the horizontal scroll smoothly. Let's start with a horizontal scrolling environment.

```html
// index.html
...
<head>
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="screen">
    <div id="content1"></div><div id="content2"></div><div id="content3"></div><div id="content4"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
...
```

```css
/* index.css */
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#screen {
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
}

#screen > div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
}
#screen > div:nth-child(1) {
  background: aqua;
}
#screen > div:nth-child(2) {
  background: blueviolet
}
#screen > div:nth-child(3) {
  background: chocolate
}
#screen > div:nth-child(4) {
  background: darkolivegreen;
}
```

A web page has now been created that has four sections and occupies one screen size per section. For smooth, snap horizontal scroll applications, let's think step by step about what we need to make code for animation.

To implement Snap, you need to know what value scroll X should move to. In the current layout, the value is the offsetLeft value of the section element. And the section size changes depending on the browser size. So the code to get the offsetLeft of the section can be created as follows:

```js
let sectionAnchorPointer = [];
const resizeHandler = () => {
  const content1 = document.getElementById('content1');
  const content2 = document.getElementById('content2');
  const content3 = document.getElementById('content3');
  const content4 = document.getElementById('content4');

  sectionAnchorPointer = [content1.offsetLeft, content2.offsetLeft, content3.offsetLeft, content4.offsetLeft];
};
addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler);
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  resizeHandler();
});
```

In order to store the section offsetLeft value from the beginning, a function was executed to update the section offsetLeft when DOMContentLoaded occurred. If you want to make it more efficient, please apply debounce to the resize event handler.

Next, when the wheel occurs, find the section to move. In order to find the section to be moved, it is necessary to determine where the section is located and then perform the calculation according to the direction of the wheel. The code is as follows:

```js
let nextSectionIndex = 0;

const getCurrentSectionIndex = () => sectionAnchorPointer.findIndex((leftValue, i, array) => {
  const scrollX = Math.ceil(window.scrollX); // Fixed a bug where scrollX was decimalized
  const rightValue = array[i + 1] ?? Infinity;
  return leftValue <= scrollX && scrollX < rightValue;
});

window.addEventListener('wheel', ({ deltaY }) => {
  const currentSectionIndex = getCurrentSectionIndex();
  const add = Math.abs(deltaY) / deltaY;

  nextSectionIndex = currentSectionIndex + add;
  nextSectionIndex = Math.min(sectionAnchorPointer.length - 1, Math.max(0, nextSectionIndex)); // To avoid pointing to a section index that does not exist
  console.log(sectionAnchorPointer[nextSectionIndex]);
});
```

To save the scroll position when accessing the page, Call the function when a DOMContentLoaded event occurs.

```js
...
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  resizeHandler();
  nextSectionIndex = getCurrentSectionIndex();
});
...
```

Next, apply the animation so that it slowly changes to the offsetLeft value of the section that needs to move the current scrollX value. For ease of understanding, let's make it a linear animation without acceleration. The code is as follows:

```js
const SCROLL_SPEED = 70; // It can be changed for speed control.
requestAnimationFrame(function scroll() {
  const nextScrollX = sectionAnchorPointer[nextSectionIndex];

  // linear animtion
  if (Math.abs(window.scrollX - nextScrollX) > SCROLL_SPEED) {
    const val = -Math.abs(window.scrollX - nextScrollX) / (window.scrollX - nextScrollX);
    window.scroll(window.scrollX + val * SCROLL_SPEED, window.scrollY);
  } else {
    window.scroll(nextScrollX, window.scrollY);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
});
```

To apply dynamic animation by adding acceleration, add the following code instead of the code above.

```js
requestAnimationFrame(function scroll() {
  const nextScrollX = sectionAnchorPointer[nextSectionIndex];

  // curve animation
  if (Math.abs(window.scrollX - nextScrollX) > 1) {
    let val = (nextScrollX - window.scrollX) / 8; // You can change 8 to another value to adjust the animation speed.
    
    val = val > 0 ? Math.max(val, 1) : Math.min(val, -1);

    window.scroll(window.scrollX + val, window.scrollY);
  } else {
    window.scroll(nextScrollX, window.scrollY);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
});
```

This is a simple example of implementation for understanding. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/smooth-snap-horizon-scroll-20f202) is a link to the project using the code. If you are interested, please refer to the following [link](https://javascript.info/js-animation) to understand Javascript animation. For your information, it would be more convenient to make an animation using a known library such as [anime.js](https://animejs.com/) or [popmotion](https://popmotion.io/).

---

This is the script code that fits your structure. Remove the existing wheel listener and insert this content.

```js
const wrap = document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-section-wrap')[1]
let sectionAnchorPointer = [];
let resultX = 0;
const resizeHandler = () => {
  sectionAnchorPointer = [...new Set([...wrap.children].map(el => el.offsetLeft))];
};
addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler);
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  resizeHandler();
  nextSectionIndex = getCurrentSectionIndex();
});
resizeHandler();

let nextSectionIndex = 0;

const getCurrentSectionIndex = () => sectionAnchorPointer.findIndex((leftValue, i, array) => {
  const scrollX = Math.ceil(resultX); // Fixed a bug where scrollX was decimalized
  const rightValue = array[i + 1] ?? Infinity;
  return leftValue <= resultX && resultX < rightValue;
});

window.addEventListener('wheel', (ev) => {
    const {deltaY} = ev;
  const currentSectionIndex = getCurrentSectionIndex();
  const add = Math.abs(deltaY) / deltaY;

  nextSectionIndex = currentSectionIndex + add;
  nextSectionIndex = Math.min(sectionAnchorPointer.length - 1, Math.max(0, nextSectionIndex)); // To avoid pointing to a section index that does not exist
  console.log(sectionAnchorPointer[nextSectionIndex]);
});

const SCROLL_SPEED = 70; // It can be changed for speed control.
requestAnimationFrame(function scroll() {
  const nextScrollX = sectionAnchorPointer[nextSectionIndex];

  // linear animtion
  if (Math.abs(resultX - nextScrollX) > SCROLL_SPEED) {
    const val = -Math.abs(resultX - nextScrollX) / (resultX - nextScrollX);
    resultX = resultX + val * SCROLL_SPEED;
  } else {
    resultX = nextScrollX;
  }
  window.scroll(resultX , 0);
  requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
});
```

Comment: I think this would work if I knew JS coding :) I'm not sure how to apply these code lines to my website. I'm not a developer, I'm just designing webpages and applying some useful codes to make some implements. My coding knowledge is not that good. I just find out how to organize the codes I found by reasoning and proceed through them by trial and error. I think I'll need a front-end developer to make it work with your way. Thank you so much for you guidance!

Comment: I thought you could understand it because you showed me the code in question. After you study the code or find a developer, it will be helpful to refer to it.

Comment: Hi again, I examined your suggestion and I think the problem is I'm using inline-flex to make it horizontal. I couldn't make it with inline-block. And I think I couldn't make your given JS code work because of that. Do you have any suggestion for that? I'll edit my main post to add my own CSS codes.

Comment: It doesn't matter which CSS layout is used in the code I created. This is because the Javascript code calculates the actual location of the rendered div and applies animation to the corresponding coordinates. This is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/smooth-snap-horizon-scroll-flex-628sv7) of the flex layout of the code above. In your code, you need to obtain offsetLeft as the target of elementor-section in elementor-section-wrap. If you don't see the example screen, refresh the preview panel on the right.

Comment: I tried to understand these codes and tried some ways to make it work on my website but I couldn't. My sections labeled as div are also in the div. If you check my front page's source, you can see this. It's a bit crowded there I know but the Elementor... I gave id to all 5 sections and changed your code to this: `document.getElementsByClassName( "elementor-section" ).innerHTML = <div id="hero"></div><div id="about"></div><div id="services"></div><div id="portfolio"></div><div id="contact"></div>;` and this also didn't worked.

Comment: Updated~~~~~~~~

Comment: Hey again, I realized that after that code, I cannot scroll in mobile or tablet. My website is vertical in the mobile and tablet. Can you also help me with this?